# Django Settings not registering changes

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-settings

Alright so I was making some changes to my project trying to make an older app work with 1.8. This required messing with the TEMPLATES.content_processors.

Tried a few changes, the project broke, reverted the changes and the project is still broken some how.

Here is my current settings.py (the relevant parts, I didn't change anything else.):

```
TEMPLATES = [

{

    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',

    'DIRS': [],

    'APP_DIRS': True,

    'OPTIONS': {

        'context_processors': [

            'django.template.context_processors.debug',

            'django.template.context_processors.request',

            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ],

    },

},

]
```

(the final bracket's indenting is because of stack overflow's formatting. It's indented properly in the script)

and this is the information from my traceback:

```
TEMPLATES   
    [{'APP_DIRS': True,
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'OPTIONS': {'context_processors'
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',               
               'django.template.context_processors.request','django.core.context_processors.requestdjango.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
```

also in the traceback is the old style TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS list that I put in before, then deleted. For some reason it is still there in django!

This is obviously the problem but for the life of my I cannot find out why it would still be there after restarting apache, then restarting the physical server after I restored from a backup.

The full error is this:

ImproperlyConfigured at /consult/

Enable 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATES setting in order to use the admin application.

but as you can see it's there.

Any help that can be offered would be most welcome.

Comment: should i delete them and see if that's why?

Comment: that worked, thank you :). can you post it as an answer or change it so I can +rep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the error message doesn't seem to match your code, a good step is to remove your `*.pyc` files and let Python recreate them.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can try.

1. Bounce your web server. (apache, manage.py runserver, etc.)
2. Clear the browser cache or just wait a little while and it will clear.
3. Also blow away any .pyc files of source files that you changed and let python recreate them again.